# Reading File Path to a Variable

Tags: path, filereader

I want to use the variable that I passed to a function which contains a file path. However, I don't get it working.

For example, I have a path like "/samba-test/log_gen/log_gen/log_generator" and when I read this path to a variable it doesn't work as expected. Please refer to my explaination in the code. My comments
are tagged with the string "VENK" . Any help would be appreciated.

```
/* caller */
```

config_path = "/samba-test/log_gen/log_gen/log_generator"
ReadWrite_Config(config_path)

```
/*definition*/
```

def ReadWrite_Timeline(lp_readpath, lp_filterlist):

```
current_parent_path = lp_readpath
current_search_list = lp_filterlist


print(current_parent_path) >>>>>> VENK - PATH prints fine here as expected <<<<<<<<. 

strings_1 = ("2e88422c-4b61-41d7-9cf9-4650edaa4e56", "2017-11-27 16:1")


for index in range(0,3):
    print (current_search_list[index])



files=None
filext=[".txt",".log"]

#outputfile = open(wrsReportFileName, "a")

for ext in filext:
    print("Current_Parent_Path",current_parent_path ) <<<<<<VENK - Prints as Expected ""
    #VENK - The above line prints as ('Current_Parent_Path', '/samba-test/log_gen/log_gen/log_generator') which is expected

    #The actual files are inside the 'varlog' where the 'varlog' folder is inside '/samba-test/log_gen/log_gen/log_generator'
    #possible problematic line below.
    varlogpath = "(current_parent_path/varlog)/*"+ext >>>>>>>>>>>  VENK- Unable to find the files if given in this format <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    print("varlogpath",varlogpath) >>>>>>>>>>>> VENK- varlogpath doesn't print as expected <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    #VENK - The above line prints as ('varlogpath', 'current_parent_path/varlog/*.txt') which I feel is problematic.

    #VENK - If I give the absolute path as below it works fine
    #varlogpath = "/samba-test/log_gen/log_gen/log_generator/varlog/*"+ext 



    files = glob.glob(varlogpath)
    for file in files:
        fname_varlog = open(file, 'r')
        outputfile.write("\n")
        outputfile.write(file)
        outputfile.write("\n")
        for line in fname_varlog:
            #if any(s in line for s in strings):
            """
            #s1 searches the mandatory arguments
            #s2 searches the optional arguments
            """
            if all(s1 in line for s1 in strings_1):
            #if all(s1 in line for s1 in strings_1) or all(s2 in line for s2 in strings_2):
                #print (file, end="")
                outputfile.write(line)
        fname_varlog.close()



outputfile.write("\n")  
outputfile.write("10.[##### Summary of the Issue #####] -- Enter Data Manually \n")
outputfile.write("\n")
outputfile.close()   
    #print (ext)
```

Comment: Language tag? What is the above?

Answer (score 0):

A path join to the variable 'current_parent_path' helped to resolve the problem (like below).

varlogpath = os.path.join(current_parent_path, "*"+ext)